# Hide menu items from authenticated users Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have `Login` menu item, and I want to hide it from uathenticated users, I try to find solutions and fount this:

[Wordpress Stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90799/how-do-i-hide-one-menu-item-link-for-logged-in-and-logged-out-users)

But for my opinion creating two separate menus is not very good idea. Maybe exists another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create two seperate menus, you will have to create a [custom menu walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function). But honestly, [creating two seperate menus](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Different_menus_for_logged-in_users) is the correct way to do it, and it's probably the easiest way too.

Alternatively, you could add a class to the menu items you want to hide, and hide them using either JavaScript and CSS for users that are not logged in, of course, that's not a very good solution.

Comment: Nice solution found here https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203106357-Add-Login-Logout-Links-To-The-Custom-Primary-Menu-Area

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS alone. When a user is logged in, WordPress adds the class '[logged-in](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class#Logged-in)' to the page's body tag.

In the menu builder, you can specify a class for an individual menu item in the same place that you set the label and title. For example you could set the class to 'logout-hide'. screenshot:

[image]

If the 'class' options is not visible, which it is not by default, turn it on in the 'Screen Options' area. See the bottom row of options in this screenshot:

[image]

Now, in your CSS you could use the following CSS rule to hide this item when users are logged in:

```
body.logged-in li.logout-hide {
    display:none;
}
```

This same approach could be used if you wanted to hide a logout item when logged in, and hide a login item when logged out.

**A note about css specificity:** You might find that even after you set the rule above, the item is not hidden. This is likely because another rule is overriding your new rule and setting the 'display' property to something visible. For example, if your menu has an ID applied to it (say, 'menu-header-menu' maybe) you will probably have to add that to your rule. i.e:

```
body.logged-in ul#menu-header-menu li.logout-hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Let us know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying Mere Development's way and theoretically it should work however I was using Chrome. Make sure you disable Chrome's cache under DevTools